# I want to add JavaScripts in JavaDoc

Tags: javascript, javadoc

```
/**
 * <div class="en">Documentation in English</div>
 * <div class="nl">Documentatie in Nederlands</div>
 */
public void myFunction() {}
```

Subsequently edit the CSS of the JavaDocs so that the user can switch languages, e.g.:

```
div.en { display:none; }
div.nl { display:block; }
```

How to add javascripts in JavaDoc?

Comment: I get the feeling you might be going a bit overkill. I would write separate docs if I need it in multiple languages, API docs should be readable with less english skills too as they're simpler IMO.

Comment: ps. "embed" might be a better word than "bury" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You might be able to do it with the `javadoc -header` option.
- You definitely can do it by subclassing the doclet and modifying its behavior. Start at the [Sun Javadoc Technology page](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/index.html).