# Change the default language in Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

The JavaDoc I generated are in Chinese. However, my comments are in English. I want to generate a whole English version JavaDoc.
How to change the language to English? The default language in my laptop and Eclipse are all Chinese, will these effect the generation of JavaDoc?

Comment: How are you generating the Javadoc?

Comment: You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482392/how-to-create-multi-language-javadocs) helpful. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Please don't add the solution into the question. Create an own answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just fixed this problem. Right click the project in Eclipse.

Export - java - javadoc - next - next - next - extra Javadoc option - enter "-locale en_US".

Then the JavaDoc are in English !

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio you can input **en** in the *locale* input box:

[image: click here to see the picture]