# How can I make stylesheet.css reflect on quick documents of javadoc?

Tags: css, android-studio, javadoc

I made a javadoc reference with this method ([How to create multi-language JavaDocs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482392/how-to-create-multi-language-javadocs)).

I changed `div` to `span` as below.

```
/**
* <span class="jp">定数クラス</span>
* <span class="en">Constant value class</span>
*/
```

stylesheet.css (for japanese)

```
span.en { display:none; }
span.jp { display:block; }
```

I could change the displayed language on web browser by switching stylesheet.
However, the stylesheet settings were not reflected in the quick document(popup reference) on Android studio.

Both languages displayed:

[image]

How can I make the stylesheet settings reflect on quick documents?
(Android studio version is 2.3.3)